# Why does Chrome not understannd "width: 50%" for a table cell?

Tags: css, google-chrome, html-table

I have a collapsible table with three header cells, but when it is opened there are four content cells in the row below. The first header cell spans two content cells. I want the first header cell to be 50 % wide also when the table is closed. With the code shown below this works in FF. But in Chrome the three header cells have the same width, when the table is closed.

The table can be found [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=Template:3-ary_Boolean_functions;_BEC;_nesting_analysis;_overview&oldid=436405615). The cell is the one marked "6, 11".

```
<table class="collapsible collapsed" style="width: 100%;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2" style="width: 50%;">A & B</th>
            <th style="width: 25%;">C</th>
            <th style="width: 25%;">D</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>D</td>
        </tr>
```

I something wrong with my code or with Chrome? And is there an intersection of what is correct and what both browsers understand?

Comment: did you try table-layout:fixed on table?

Comment: That did the trick, thanks. Also, I did not need to specify the width anymore. Still, should it not be possible to specify a cell width in Chrome?

Comment: You can specify cell widths in Chrome for most cases. Allocating width to colspan cells is complicated and the engines all do weird things there. That said, I agree that this should be considered a Chrome bug. The algorithm that allocates colspan widths is currently being reworked but probably won't be released until like Chrome 90. And I don't know off the top of my head if this case's behavior will be changed.

Answer (score 0):

`table-layout:fixed` gives the closed table the proportions of the open one.
[Here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=Template:3-ary_Boolean_functions;_BEC;_nesting_analysis;_overview&diff=prev&oldid=436410862) is the change.